# I need to differentiate an observational study from an experimental study and need reasons why

Tags: self-study, observational-study

So these are the two studies which I have been given.

Study 1: An orchardist is concerned about the presence of a species of (hungry!) bugs that have infested the apple trees in his orchard. There are three different sprays available that may eliminate this pest and the orchardist wants to test the effectiveness of these to see which one, if any, is worth using. There are 80 apple trees that are infested with the bug. The orchardist randomly assigned the trees into four groups with each of the three sprays being randomly allocated to one of the groups, and the remaining group was left untreated. Two weeks after spraying, the orchardist calculated a “bug score” for each tree by taking a random sample of 100 leaves from the tree and counting the number of these leaves that have bugs on them.

Study 2: A market research company has been contracted to carry out a large survey. The survey involves asking a detailed series of questions that usually takes between 15 to 25 minutes to answer. The company is aware that the longer it takes to answer the questionnaire, the less likely people are to complete the survey. They conduct a small pilot study to investigate which of the two questionnaire designs will take the least time to answer. 50 subjects were randomly allocated into two groups of 25; one group is interviewed using the first questionnaire design, and the other group is interviewed using the second questionnaire design. For each subject, the time taken to complete the questionnaire is recorded.

I need to find out what kind of studies they are; an experiment or observational study.